# Is it possible to test that assets are well minified and concataned in production (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I would like to know if it's possible to create a rspec/capybara or any tools available (free or paid) on the web that my assets (css, js,...) are actually REALLY/effectively minified and concatanated in the Production environment?

Seems impossible as my tests always deal with local code and not things in 'production'...

thanks

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by "REALLY/effectively minified". Generally, no, you don't need to test this, any more than you need to write tests for `ActiveRecord::Base`. Test *your code*, don't test Rails. Rails already has exhaustive specs.

Comment: As minification and concatantion improve speed by reduing size of css and js files, and as my assets preloading/minification has failed in the past when deploying to heroku (without creating an error i could spot), i wanted to know if a system would enable me to never miss any deploy where everything seems fine but in reality the assets have not been well minified or con catanated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your request specs to test minified assets, just precompile your assets and turn off `config.assets.debug` and `config.assets.compile` in `config/environments/test.rb`.

Generally, there is no reason to do this. You can assume that Rails will successfully minify your assets. Precompiling assets before your tests will slow you down **tremendously** and make it more or less impossible to practice anything resembling test-driven development.